# Access denied removing `__debug_bin` in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debug, debugger

After debugging a go program, the `__debug_bin` file is leftover and is not getting removed, throwing an access denied error. I tried running VSCode with admin privileges but it's the same.

I would like to get rid of this error if possible.
See here my simple setup:

[image]

`launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

and my `.gitignore` file:

```
__debug_bin
.vscode
*.exe
```

OS: Windows 10

I can manually delete the generated file but then it gets regenerated back and error returns on next debug session.

Comment: Are you using WSL1? Or Git?

Comment: No WSL. I use git yes @harrymc but I am ignoring it:

```__debug_bin
/.vscode
*.exe```

Comment: The Go extension may be trying to delete the folder too early. This works in Linux but not on Windows.

Comment: Yeah. I guess that's what it looks like it's happening. Maybe I need to file an issue for the go compiler for Windows.

Comment: The Go _compiler_ is entirely unrelated. This is (almost certainly) exclusively about the Go VS Code extension.

Comment: Oops. I meant the VSCode Go extension.

Comment: Not sure about `go` but if the __debug_bin file started recently showing up, then this is more likely a vscode issue that recently got resolved - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105191#event-3805263834

Comment: @SILENT I updated VSCode to latest version, and the issue persists.

Comment: That link refers to `debug.log` though not `__debug_bin`

Answer (score 1):

The post
[Unable to Debug Go Program in Visual Studio Code #83505](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83505)
seems to be about the same error, caused by git.

The solution there was:

> This looks to be cause by git. If you add `*__` in general or specifically that `*__debug_bin` to your `gitignore` file thingy, the error goes away.

Comment: I have it in my gitinore file (I edited my question to add the gitignore contents). I don't believe this is related to my error. More like a Visual Studio Code error than Git I think. NOTE: This is happening at the end of the debug session.

Comment: See these gitinore files : [simple version](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/VisualStudioCode.gitignore) and [full version](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore).

Comment: I skimmed through them, but don't see anything about the `__debug_bin` in there. Might be related to the go debugger I suppose.

Comment: Also check if the solutions in this old [thread](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/296249/Visual-Studio-2010-Access-Denied-Errors) apply to your case.

Comment: It seems to be referring to Visual Studio IDE not Code. It's a different software.

Comment: Not totally different.

Comment: @harrymc, in your comment simple version is actually VisualStudioCode.gitignore and  full version is VisualStudio.gitignore. The thread is about VisualStudioCode

Answer (score 1):

Sometime docker doesn't allow you to access files in the remote container. Use this docker option to run your container `--security-opt=seccomp:unconfined`

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this problem was a different process was attempting to access, or had an open handle to the "__debug_bin" file when the debugger (dlv.exe, the delve debugger) tried to delete the binary.

In the case of Git, a git related process was probably trying to check the file for changes; adding the file to the ignore list probably stopped that process from accessing it.

In my case; I dug into the file access via Process Monitor, and noticed that "MsMpEng.exe" had access to the file right before the dlv.exe debugger received the "CANNOT DELETE" result from the filesystem.  MsMpEng.exe is "Microsoft Malware Protection Engine"; obviously scanning for malware.  Adding "dlv.exe" to the MS Defender AV exclusion list pretty much eliminated the error.

If you have some other process hitting the file, I would suggest checking to see if that process has exclusions you could set.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing when I closed or quit my program myself, but if you use the little "stop debugging" button from within VSCode it should quit cleanly without that annoying error.

Quitting program via Alt+F4:

```
could not remove C:\Users\whatever\__debug_bin: remove C:\Users\whatever\__debug_bin: Access is denied.
Process exiting with code: 0
```

Quitting via Shift+F5 in VSCode:

```
Failed to get state - Process 15260 has exited with status 0
Process exiting with code: 0
```

Comment: The issue I am having is not when closing the editor but when I am stopping the debugger session (after every run).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, but after I closed VS Code and re-opened it, I can debug the program normally by pressing F5 key.